# jQuery: Quick question. How to select string variable?

Tags: jquery, string, select

**EDIT:** I would like to *`avoid`* doing something like this:

```
var str = 'Hello'; 
if ( str == 'Hello') { 
    alert(str); 
}
```

I would rather do:

```
var str = 'Hello'; 
$(str).filter(':contains("Hello")').each(function(){ 
    alert(this) 
});
```

I've tried a lot of things:

```
$(str).text().method1().method2().method3();
$(str).val().method1().method2().method3();
$(str).contents().method1().method2().method3();
```

Nothing worked. Is it possible to do this?

Thank you for your time.

Kind regards,
Marius

Comment: You might want to try and explain your motivation. It isn't currently clear why you would want want to use jQuery for something it wasn't designed for, instead of using the simple javascript snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the value in an array, they you can use the `grep` method to filter out the items in the array that matches a criteria:

```
$($.grep([str], function(e){
  return e == 'Hello';
})).each(function(){
  alert(this);
});
```

You can also make a plugin to make it more like the code that you wished for:

```
(function($){
  $.fn.eq = function(str) {
    return $($.grep(this, function(e){ return e == str; }));
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
var str = 'Hello';
$([str]).eq('Hello').each(function(){
  alert(this);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

jQuery selectors don't work like that. The whole idea is that they select elements of the Document Object Model (DOM). In other words, tags in your HTML document (page).

If you want to use a string variable, you can just access it directly as `str`. No jQuery is even required.

That said, is there a specific jQuery method (or methods) that you wanted to use to manipulate a string?

Comment: I want to avoid doing this:

var str = Hello;
if ( str == 'Hello') {
alert(str);
}

I would rather do: $(str).filter('contains("Hello")').each(function(){ alert(this) });